# How to use PHP generators without foreach?

Tags: php, generator

Here's a simple JavaScript generator (via: http://blog.carbonfive.com/2013/12/01/hanging-up-on-callbacks-generators-in-ecmascript-6/)

```
function* powGenerator() {
  var result = Math.pow(yield "a", yield "b");
  return result;
}

var g = powGenerator();
console.log(g.next().value);   // "a", from the first yield
console.log(g.next(10).value); // "b", from the second
console.log(g.next(2).value);  // 100, the result
```

I'm trying to model something similar with PHP but it's a bit of a headache.

```
<?php
function powGenerator() {
  return pow((yield 'a'), (yield 'b'));
}
```

Before I go further, I get this error in PHP

> Fatal error: Generators cannot return values using "return"

Ok, so maybe I'll just use another yield to get the final value out? ...

```
<?php
function powGenerator() {
  yield pow((yield 'a'), (yield 'b'));
}

$g = powGenerator(); //=> Generator {#180}
echo $g->send(10);   //=> "b"
echo $g->send(2);    //=> 100
```

OK, so I got my value back, but there's two major issues here

1. **Where did my `"a"` go?** — Notice in the JS example I was able to access the both the `"a"` and the `"b"` yielded values as well as the `100` final result.
2. **The generator is still not done!** — I have to call `send` an additional time to complete the generator

   ```
   $g->valid();   //=> true
   $g->send('?'); //=> null
   $g->valid();   //=> false
   ```

---

From PHP [Generator::send](http://php.net/manual/en/generator.send.php)

> `public mixed Generator::send ( mixed $value )`
>
> Sends the given value to the generator as the result of the current `yield` expression and resumes execution of the generator.
>
> If the generator is not at a `yield` expression when this method is called, it will first be let to advance to the first `yield` expression before sending the value. As such it is not necessary to "prime" PHP generators with a [Generator::next()](http://php.net/manual/en/generator.next.php) call (like it is done in Python).

Emphasis on "As such it is not necessary to "prime" PHP generators with a `Generator::next()`". OK, but what does that really mean? I don't have to "prime" it like the JavaScript example, but the first yielded value is also getting swallowed.

Can anyone explain how you're meant to step through generators **without** using a `foreach`?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The first yielded value wasn't swallowed, you just never looked at it.

```
$g = powGenerator();
echo $g->current(); //a
```

You're then twice sending in values and resuming execution, `$g->valid()` is `true` after this because you haven't resumed after the third `yield` - the generator isn't complete and there may be more for it to do. Consider:

```
function powGenerator() {
    yield pow((yield 'a'), (yield 'b'));
    echo "Okay, finishing here now!\n";
}

$g = powGenerator();
echo $g->current(), "\n"; //a
echo $g->send(10), "\n";  //b
echo $g->send(2), "\n";   //100
$g->next();               // Resumes execution of the generator,
                          // which prints its own message and completes.
var_dump($g->valid());    //false
```

This'll output:

```
a
b
100
Okay, finishing here now!
bool(false)
```

---

Now in PHP 7 you *can* [return from a generator](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/generator-return-expressions).

```
function powGenerator() {
    return pow((yield 'a'), (yield 'b'));
    echo "This will never print.";
}

$g = powGenerator();
echo $g->current(), "\n"; //a
echo $g->send(10), "\n";  //b
echo $g->send(2), "\n";   // Prints just the newline, you're moving on
                          // to a return which you must get explicitly.
var_dump($g->valid());    // Generator complete, you're free to get the return.
echo $g->getReturn(), "\n";
```

Which outputs:

```
a
b

bool(false)
100
```

---

As for stepping through them without a `foreach` - [Generator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.generator.php) implements [Iterator](http://php.net/manual/en/class.iterator.php), so it's got appropriate methods to treat it as such: [current](http://php.net/manual/en/generator.current.php), [key](http://php.net/manual/en/generator.key.php), [next](http://php.net/manual/en/generator.next.php), [rewind](http://php.net/manual/en/generator.rewind.php), and [valid](http://php.net/manual/en/generator.valid.php). With the caveat that `rewind` will throw an exception if you call it on a generator that's already begun.

An example which does this and also demonstrates PHP 7's new [generator delegation](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/generator-delegation):

```
function letterGenerator() {
    yield from range('a', 'z');
}

$g = letterGenerator();

while ($g->valid()) {
    echo $g->current();
    $g->next();
}
```

Output:

```
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
```

Comment: Ok, the use of `current` and `next` is at least consistent with existing array implementations, but not being able to specify the end of a generator is really dumb, imo. The extra `next()` call to terminate the generator makes it really hard to build your own programmatic stepping around this. The documentation makes it sound like PHP generators are great not having to "prime" them like Python does. They just end up with a clunky API anyway. Classic PHP.