# How to move on to next line while letting generator running in the background

Tags: php, generator, yield

I'm not sure if I put in my requirement in right word above. What I what to do is, move on to next line of code after started the generator.

The generator has to be started before the next line executed. The problem I'm facing now is that, I have no idea how to move on to the next line while letting the generator do what it need to do.

the generator function using rethinkdb:

```
function getRealTimeUpdate()
{
$products = r\table("tableOne")->changes()->run($conn);

foreach ($products as $product) {
   yield $product['new_val'];
}
}
```

The caller function located in: `server.php`

```
  $server = IoServer::factory(

            new HttpServer(
                new WsServer(
                    new Chat()
                )
            ),

            8180,
            '0.0.0.0'

        );
$update= rethink::getRealTimeUpdate();
 foreach ($update as $value) {
    var_dump($value);//this prints the latest data
    }
```

But I need to run this line as well, maybe just after called the generator function. But now it seems like, its not invoked.

```
$server->run();
```

I referred all these sources, I've failed to understand and apply to my code.

https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.generators.overview.php

[How to use PHP generators without foreach?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32960408/how-to-use-php-generators-without-foreach)

Comment: debug this line `$products = r\table("tableOne")->changes()->run($conn);`

Comment: it returns a cursor object from rethinkdb.